# Times loop isn't looping

Tags: ruby, loops

I'm creating a little script that will send 10 jobs to a printer. I'm trying to loop one of my methods using a `times` loop except when I run the program, it won't loop, it just send one job..

Example:

```
[<user>@<server> ruby]$ ruby clean_printer laser32
request id is laser32-1038115 (1 file(s))
[<user>@<server> ruby]$
```

Am I doing something wrong to where this won't loop..?

Source:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby

class CleanPrinter

  attr_accessor :printer

  def initialize(printer)
    @printer = printer
  end

  def create_jobs
    exec("lp -d #{@printer} test.txt")
  end

  def loop
    10.times do
      create_jobs
    end
  end
end

test = CleanPrinter.new(ARGV[0])
test.loop
```

Yes it's a class, yes I will take it out of the class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that `exec()` actually *replaces* the current process image, thereby effectively exiting your program on the first iteration. You might want to switch to using `system()` instead.

Comment: Of simply use backticks rather than `system` if the return-code of the called program isn't important.

Comment: @theTinMan There's another consideration: `system()` will send the child's output (unless redirected in the shell command) to the same device as the parent's, whereas backticks will open up a pipe and write into it, then read from it.

Comment: So why wouldn't `exec` work, isn't it basically the same concept of using backticks?

Comment: Please read the documentation for `exec`, `system`, `%x` and backticks which are all in [Kernel](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html). That will explain the difference.

Comment: @theTinMan I did read the documentation, and they're all basically the same concept. `%x` is just another use for backticks, and `system`, is a `system call the uses the current STDIN`. `exec` begins a new process and doesn't return. I get it. What I'm saying is aren't _ALL_ shell commands system calls, so why wouldn't it be logical that using `exec` instead of `system` would work just as well as one another?

Comment: @Bam In one way, they're the same: they use the shell (at least by the type of call you're issuing to `exec()`). But whereas `system()` *forks a new process* and *then* replaces the running program *in the child process*, `exec()` will simply do so while overwriting *the calling process*. That's the difference.

Comment: @YamMarcovic Awh okay, thank you for the clarification.